# Proper way to manage reminder when creating event with google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the google-api-php-client within my php webapp since a long time to insert calendar event, drive file, send mail etc.. All is working fine.

Regarding the calendar, i have a request from the users to remove the default reminders on a particular type of event.

I used the following process : All the users of my google app have shared their calendar with a specific account and i use this specific adress to setup the library.

I'm not able to used the specified method described in the doc here :

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

the following code :

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  ...
  ...
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));
```

will only work if i use directly the targeted account with OAuth in the "try it" on the google page.

Say i want to create an event for bla@bla.com without retrieving his default reminders using the try it google page, i have to use bla@bla.com to OAuth. In this scenario, the default reminders are not used and i get the 2 reminders (email 24 * 60 and popup 10), as expected.

If i use my specific account to OAuth, i'm able to create the event on bla@bla.com account (since the calendar is shared) but in this case, the useDefault => false seems omitted and the default reminder set up on bla@bla.com are used instead of the 2 expected...

As the result is the same using my webApp or the google try it page, i assume that it's not a wrong usage of the google-api-php-client.

Any help would be appreciated.

Seb

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a raised [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/233) regarding the use of `setUseDefault(false);` And based from the thread

> Using the `string` instead of `boolean` seems to solve this issue.

This was fixed by replacing

`$set_reminders->setUseDefault(false);`

with

`$set_reminders->setUseDefault("false");`

I hope that works for you too.

Comment: Thx for your help but i have already tried this fixed and it didn't help with my issue. The problem i have seems to be related to the fact that i'm using a separate account (which has been authorize on the target calendar) to create the event. Using directly the targeted account works fine, but using the separate account, the event is created but it use the default reminders, event from the "try it" page of the insert api call from google calendar api doc.